# How to remove extra space or gap between the tag in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello I am  scraping an li tag within a div website from website. And I get the output with lots a space in it how can I remove the extra space from the tag
I am using python 3.5.1 and BeautifulSoup for scraping
My Output:

```
[<li>

        GUANGZHOU ADS AUDIO SCIENCE &amp; TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD.

            </li>, <li>

              SHIMA ADS INDUSTRIAL DISTRICT GUANGZHOU GUANGDONG CHINA

            </li>, <li>

        GUANGDONGGUANGZHOU

            </li>, <li>

              510440

            </li>, <li>

              http://www.adsaudio.cc

            </li>]
[<li>

        GUANGDONG TEXTILES IMPORT &amp; EXPORT COMPANY LTD.

            </li>, <li>

              GUANGDONG ,NO.168 XIAO BEI RD.,GUANGZHOU

            </li>, <li>

        GUANGDONGGUANGZHOU

            </li>, <li>

              510045

            </li>, <li>

              http://www.gdtex.com

            </li>]
```

And I want the output like

```
 GUANGZHOU ADS AUDIO SCIENCE &amp; TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD.
 SHIMA ADS INDUSTRIAL DISTRICT GUANGZHOU GUANGDONG CHINA
 GUANGDONG TEXTILES MANSION,NO.168 XIAO BEI RD.,GUANGZHOU
 GUANGDONG ,NO.168 XIAO BEI RD.,GUANGZHOU
```

How can I remove the extra space or gap

Comment: You need the tag also?

Comment: `re.sub("\s+"," ",my_text)` will probably get you close enough ..

Comment: @Mauro Baraldi  No tag is not needed

Comment: @Joran Beasley  It say TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: well my_text needs to be a string or bytes-like  object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `get_text` method from BeautifulSoup

```
items = soup.find_all("li")
for item in items:
    print item.get_text().strip()
```

Comment: Yes, But the thing is that in this li tag there are information like campany name, Address, Email. And I want only to get Company Name and Address. So how can I get that

Comment: Post some example of data you expect to extract

Comment: Yes it is retriving, But I want show it like
company name is = "NAME OF COMPANY"
company address  = "COMPANY ADDRESS"

Comment: @JohnD.Doucette if you want `Yes it is retriving, But I want show it like company name is = "NAME OF COMPANY" company address = "COMPANY ADDRESS"` then you should not try to merely strip html tags but to traverse html by XPath, fetching and storing each item accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) on the text you are getting back from `Beautiful Soup`.

Let's say you are using something like this to extract the text from the `li` tag:  `text = soup.find('li').get_text()`, then add a call to `strip()` on text `text.strip()` and that should remove the whitespaces at both ends.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_li_texts(html):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
  li_list = soup.findAll('li')

  li_texts = []
  for li in li_list:
    text = li.get_text().strip()
    li_texts.append(text)
  return li_texts

html = '<li>\n\n        GUANGZHOU ADS AUDIO SCIENCE &amp; TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD.\n\n            </li>, <li>\n\n              SHIMA ADS INDUSTRIAL DISTRICT GUANGZHOU GUANGDONG CHINA\n\n            </li>, <li>\n\n        GUANGDONGGUANGZHOU\n\n            </li>, <li>\n\n              510440\n\n            </li>, <li>\n\n              http://www.adsaudio.cc\n\n            </li>'
texts = get_li_texts(html)
>> [u'GUANGZHOU ADS AUDIO SCIENCE & TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD.',
>> u'SHIMA ADS INDUSTRIAL DISTRICT GUANGZHOU GUANGDONG CHINA',
>> u'GUANGDONGGUANGZHOU',
>> u'510440',
>> u'http://www.adsaudio.cc']
```

Comment: But I cant add all the li tag here to strip it. and I am scraping a thousands of company details.